# JComboBox selecting object items using a CellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, selection, jcombobox, cellrenderer

I have the problem that I am using a JComboBox with a CellRenderer to display values of my class AddressNode. However, when I select an Item from the DropDown, it'll insert the Object Value into the EditorComponent instead of the Rendered Value. The code for my CellRenderer is the following:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    if (value instanceof AddressNode) {
        AddressNode node = (AddressNode) value;
        String displayString = "";

       displayString += node.getStreet() + " " + node.getHouse();
       if (node.getCity() != null)
           displayString += (", " + node.getCity());
       if (node.getPostCode() != null)
           displayString += (" " + node.getPostCode());

        setText(displayString);
    }
    return this;
}
```

When I for example select an Item from my DropDown list, it'll then set the value of the EditorComponent to something like: Model.AddressNode@581280a8.
Whereas I wanted it to set the value to the same String that my CellRenderer displayed.

Comment: 1. Renderer is designated to decorate, highlighting, looks like as every code lines inside if (value instanceof AddressNode) { is in conflict with this idea implemented in API, 2. value Model.AddressNode@581280a8 is about wrong usage of array in Java/Swing Objects

Comment: A combo box is not designed to edit an object. It is only designed to edit a simple String. What you see in the editor is the `toString()` representation of your object.

Comment: In addition to the above, we don't know what `node` is (and what its related functions are).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

```
if (value instanceof AddressNode) {
    AddressNode node = (AddressNode) value;
    String displayString = "";

   displayString += node.getStreet() + " " + node.getHouse();
   if (node.getCity() != null)
       displayString += (", " + node.getCity());
   if (node.getPostCode() != null)
       displayString += (" " + node.getPostCode());

    //setText(displayString);
}
```

return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, displayString, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, but it still sets the value of the EditorComponent to the Object Value upon selection with your code.